# Google Sheets script that enables you to insert/write a word in a cell when clicked while assigned to a drawing (acting as a button)

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm making a workout tracker that tracks my workout almost every day with a bit of odd rules in it. What I wanted to do is a **button** *(with the use of a drawing and a script assigned to it)* ***that inserts the word*** "**skipped**" ***whenever I click on it***. I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Here is the link to a copy of my tracker: [sample tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J0n05lwY7nj93D1ukb5Zc1ACr-58UZkGt4ixKs6HQRQ/edit?usp=sharing)

To summarize it up, I want to create a button that serves only **(1)** purpose, ***to insert the word*** **"skipped"** in a cell.

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question and your shared Spreadsheet and the included script, I cannot understand about your goal and your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike,  I wanted a button to insert a specific word (skipped) to a cell when clicked. Just like the (done) button on my sheet( a drawing with a script assigned to it). When I click on it, the current date is inserted to a blank cell. I want a button (skipped) to insert the word "skipped" just by clicking on it. To insert a text in the cell. I am looking for a script that allows me to insert a specific word when  assigned to the drawing(and acts as the function of a button)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `When I click on it, the current date is inserted to a blank cell.`, where is the blank cell? About `I want a button (skipped) to insert the word "skipped" just by clicking on it. To insert a text in the cell.`, you want to put "the current date" and insert the word "skipped"? About `I am looking for a script that allows me to insert a specific word when assigned to the drawing(and acts as the function of a button)`, I cannot understand about this. By the way, in your shared Spreadsheet, where is the button?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I want to pull out the specific word " skipped" . The button is the drawing. The one beside the other drawing "done". The word "Skipped" above the sheet, if you right click on it, there will be 3 dots, and then you can use it to assign a script. So when you click on it afterwards, the script automatically applies to the cell. So the drawing with a script assigned to it functions as a button.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal and your current situation. When I could correctly understand about them, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue, soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the existing scirpt attached to your sample spreadsheet, you need to modify it as following:

```js
function Skipped() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  .getActiveCell().setValue('SKIPPED');  
}
```

This will assign the value "SKIPPED" to the cell that it is active at the moment you click the button.

Don't forget to assign the function `Skipped` to your button by clicking on the "three vertical dots" on the button, selecting `Assign script` and typing in the name of the function without the brackets`()` - `Skipped`.

Comment: Thank you so much @ziganotschka. This is exactly what I was looking for. God bless!